# Oracle endeca cas xml manipulator

Tags: xml, etl, endeca, endeca-workbench

Could anybody specify the steps to crawl xml document data into forge readable xml through CAS (Content Acquisition System) manipulators in Oracle Endeca Guided Search?

Comment: any help on this ??? please clarify if the question is not  clear :)